# Regex in mod_rewrite to match URLs NOT ending with this OR that

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

What is the regex for this?

Match if string

> - NOT ( ends in `.php` OR ends in `.html` OR contains `/` )

Thank you!

Edit: I need the `NOT` part because the expression is to be used on an Apache mod rewrite, since I can't change the logic of `mod_rewrite` to avoid the `NOT`.

Edit: My initial effort was `([^/]+)(\.html)$(^\.php)$` - which is monstrously wrong

Comment: What effort have you put in so far?

Comment: ([^/]+)(\.html)$(^\.php)$  -- which is monstrusly wrong

Comment: It's still good to put it in the question, to show that you've made an effort.

Comment: Please, for the love all that is good.  Use the formatting features! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apache mod_rewrite *does* support negation, according to [this document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

> In mod_rewrite, the NOT character 
>   ('!') is also available as a possible
>   pattern prefix. This enables you to
>   negate a pattern; to say, for
>   instance: ``if the current URL does
>   NOT match this pattern''. This can be
>   used for exceptional cases, where it
>   is easier to match the negative
>   pattern, or as a last default rule.

So you should be able to do something like:

```
!^(.*?/.*|.*?\.(?:php|html)$)$
```

And that should match anything which does not contain / and does not end in .php or .html

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. I was not aware of the ! feature. Hopefuly, I 'll ask in a better way next time.

Comment: Is it possible to add this as variable now ? I tried 
RewriteRule !^(.*?/.*|.*?\.(?:php|html)$)$ headers.php?a=$1 [NC,L] but it won't pass the variable

Comment: I guess since you're going a negative match, there's no direct way for the group to match, since you're matching things that might not match the group, so we need a non-negated match which excludes what you want. I can't remember if mod_rewrite supports negative lookbehind, but try this `RewriteRule ^([^/]*(?<!\.html$)(?<!\.php$))$ headers.php?a=$1 [NC,L]` and see if it works?

Answer (score 5):

It's a whole lot easier to do positive matches in regex than negative matches.  Try searching for `ends in .php OR ends in .html OR contains /` and reverse the logic in your program.

With strict regular expressions, there isn't a general way to negate a given expression.  With PCRE's you have the advantage of negative look-aheads, which significantly simplify the process of constructing a negated search, at the expense of performance.

```
^([^/]*\.(?!html$|php$)[^./]*)|[^/.]$
```

Comment: I can't because I need it for an Apache rewrite rule. :(

Comment: Looks like mod_rewrite does do negation - and I've added an appropriate answer for that - but I'd probably still go with the expression Eclipse has just added.

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex -

```
(.*\.php$)|(.*\.html$)|(.*\/.*)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it misses the NOT part. It matches "foo.php" "fo/o" and "foo.html" . It should match all but that.