# Rewrite rule does not pass $1 when using !?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using this rule:

```
RewriteRule !^(.*?/.*|.*?\.(?:php|html)$)$ headers.php?a=$1 [L]
```

(based on the great contributions on [Regex match this OR that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345747/regex-match-this-or-that))

It rewrites to `headers.php` when I type `localhost/foo` but the `a` variable is empty instead of `foo` (I checked with `var_dump($_REQUEST)`)

Any idea why? I tried using

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !headers
```

but it wasn't that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is negated, so it is executed if and only if the regular expression *doesn't* match the URI being processed. Since the capturing group doesn't match `localhost/foo`, there's nothing for the regex engine to put into `$1`. The solution is to avoid the use of negation in your `RewriteRule` directive, and instead use `RewriteCond` directives to check the negated regex. The following ruleset should work. (I haven't test it, though. It's possible that there's a mistake somewhere.)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.*/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|php)$
RewriteRule (.*) headers.php?a=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Great idea! The sample code does not work, but you gave me a great lead to work on :) Thanks!

Comment: I edited the code about a minute ago to fix a mistake; make sure you're testing the latest version. (I'm still not sure it works, though. I have no Apache server handy to test it on.)

Comment: Thanks again, there 's still some error somewhere. It returns `The requested URL /foooo was not found on this server.`

Comment: Oops, I think the slash character I had at the start of the rewrite rule shouldn't be there. Try the version I just put up.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your efforts! Unfortunately, it is still not working. I am trying to modify it, I still haven't got it right though.

Comment: It seems the problem lies on the first line. I am trying to mend it and will post again!

Comment: Hmm, I've just tried it on my development server and it works fine. Are you sure you enabled mod_rewrite with a `RewriteEngine on` directive? If you have, and it still doesn't work, are you putting the rules in a .htaccess file, or the main Apache config file?

Comment: It is on and its on an .htaccess file. Does it play any role that I have put everything (and the script) on a subdirectory? like `localhost/script/.htaccess`

Comment: Oh, I think it's because you're running the rules from a subdirectory! Apache strips the directory prefix from `RewriteRule` URIs, but it doesn't apply the same behavior to the `REQUEST_URI` variable. If you change the first line to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/script/.*/`, then everything should work properly.

Comment: Also, if it still doesn't work, make sure you have `AllowOverride all` set in the root `<Directory>` block in the main configuration file (httpd.conf).

Comment: Fantastic!! I was going mad :o) The only problem now (surprise!) is that it also redirects /script/ to /script/headers.php , which is undisired since my code is on index.php and I 'd like it to be called when it 's access like /script/ (the standard behaviour).

Comment: That part's easy. :) Change the pattern in the last line from `(.*)` to `(.+)`. This causes the pattern to match only when there is at least one character in the filename, so /script/ will no longer be matched, and therefore Apache's default index.php redirect will take over.

Comment: You are a GOD! Words can't express my gratitude for your helping me. I was going totally mad with this. I wish we could drink some beer together!

Comment: No problem, man. I was in a very similar boat a couple of months ago: I was stuck with a mod_rewrite problem I couldn't solve if my life depended on it. I love mod_rewrite because it's so useful, but actually writing rewrite rules is definitely a pain in the neck.